# Passing request headers to all requests using cypress

Tags: request, http-headers, cypress

I want to intercept request headers for my application globally for all the requests and routes including html,js ,css

Tried below code but didn't work
tried cy.server
cy.route

code that i tried for intercepting.

```
'use strict'
describe(`TodoMVC using Cypress`, function () {
  it('passing request header', () => {

    cy.server({
      whitelist: (xhr) => {

        return xhr.method === 'GET' && /\.(jsx?|html|css)(\?.*)?$/.test(xhr.url)
      },
      onAnyRequest: (route,  proxy) => {
        proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('Referer',  '***'),
        proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','***')


      }
    })

    var options = {
      url: 'http://localhost:8080',
      headers: {'Referer': '***','Authorization' :'**='}
    };
   cy.visit(options);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still ranks high in SEO. So, you can now use `cy.intercept` to accomplish this. Their [documentation on intercept](https://docs-vercel.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) has way more information in it, but to add a header to all requests to a specific host you can do something like the following:

```
// this beforeEach needs to be at the global level, not inside a test
beforeEach(() => {

  // baseUrl should be configured in your cypress config
  cy.intercept(`${Cypress.config('baseUrl')}/**`, (req) => {
    req.headers["My-Header-Key"] = "My Header Value";
  });

});
```